# Is this objective on a optimization problem convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Is this objective convex? If not is there a way to make it convex?

I am trying to optimize the values of the matrix A for some defined values of the vectors x,y,w

$ min_A: \sum_{m} \Bigg({\dfrac{x_m * y_m + \sum (A_m\odot w)}{x_m + \sum A_m}}-10\Bigg)^2$

$A_m$ is the column m of the matrix $A$

$x_m$ is the value m of the vector $x$

Thank you

with $\odot$ I mean elementwise multiplication

Comment: The sums in the fraction are also over $m$?

Comment: Yes. What I am trying to indicate is: the sum of all of the values of the vector inside.